# session lost in MultipartRequest

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets, jakarta-ee

I'm adding in file uploading features to my application. I'm having a problem that whenever I use enctype ="multipart/form-data" in my jsp page, the session will become null. It works fine when I remove the above enctype, but the file uploading no longer function.
Do you have any idea how to over come this problem?
Any suggestion will be highly appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you paste the relevant code?

Comment: am setting session attribute in a.jsp and am trying to access this attribute in b.jsp , in between this am using jupload.jar, while displaying jupload am printing this values in a.jsp its working fine, when i click upload it redirects to b.jsp but here values are null a.jsp code   pg.session.setAttribute( "projId", projId ); in a.jsp onclick  <PARAM name="actionURL" value="/b.jsp"> this statement redirects to b.jsp here String strCurUsrId   = (String)pg.session.getAttribute("projId"); but it is returning null can u figure it out please

Answer (score 0):

From your description it seems that not the session is null but you don't get the attributes from the session in the way you used to.

Try something like [Apache Commons Fileupload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html) to have a quite easy solution.

Comment: yes you are right session attributs are returning null. but using Apache Commons Fileupload at a time only one file can be uploaded . i have a requirement that multiple files needs to uploaded at atime .

Comment: AFAIK, Fileupload will allow you to upload multiple files at once. You'd just have to iterate over the `FileItem`s returned by `ServletFileUpload#parseRequest()`.

Comment: but while browsing file, multiple file selection is not possible right.actually previously i was using tomcat 5.0, jdk1.4 it was working fine but now i changed to tomcat 7.0, jdk1.6. now session attributes returning null.

Comment: Well, multiple file selection is not possible in any browser that I know of if you don't use flash or the like. You can use multiple input fields to select multiple files and then upload those with a single submit. Did you use multiple file selection before? If so, how?